# React - are propTypes unecessary if also unit testing the component?

Tags: reactjs

If you are unit testing a React component, using Mocha + Enzyme for example, and the unit tests for this component include testing the props, is it safe to say that defining `propTypes` for that component is unecessary?

Answer (score 2):

No, as the `propTypes` can throw warnings in developer mode that can inform other developers about potential missing props, or prop type differences.

The `propTypes` purpose isn't mitigated by unit tests around it. Let's not also forget that as the app grows and more people get involved they may forget their unit tests, and then we lose the benefit of **[type checking](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)** that the `propTypes` provide.

Comment: *"as the app grows and more people get involved they may forget their unit tests"* -- This is strictly my opinion, but with projects of this size some typed preprocessing will be needed anyways; although this starts shifting into the domain of typed JavaScript supersets, such as TypeScript or Flow. I'm not familiar with the latter, but the former effectively renders `propTypes` obsolete.

Comment: Yea, it's worth noting that propTypes offers no benefit to the code but is a great documentation tool. Also as you said it really comes into it's own when TypeScript and Flow are considered. 
+1 to the power to typed languages. I love the direction JS is heading in, but it's good to have the benefit of both